# Show that the harmonic series is $\Theta(\log n)$

Tags: inequality, algorithms

> Show that the harmonic series is $\Theta(\log n)$.

This breaks down to show that $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i} = \mathcal{O}(\log n)$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i} = \Omega(\log n)$. Following the hint, I defined function $f$ as increase each denominator to the next power of 2. So $f(\frac{1}{3})=\frac{1}{4}$.

Then, we have $S = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i} > 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1-0.5^{n-1}}{0.5}.$ We would like $S \ge C\log n$ to be true. If we can show that $S\ge Cn$ then we win. But then I couldn't see the connection between $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}$ and $n$... I suppose some simple algebra trick should do it but I couldn't find one.

Comment: In *Concrete Mathematics* (by Knuth and others) there are successive proofs showing the asymptotic form of the harmonic series out to several terms past the $\log n - \gamma$.  It is worth reading these proofs.

Comment: @MarkFischler I was given that result but I assume that's what I need to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw the curve $y=\frac{1}{x}$. Draw rectangles with base $[1,2]$ and height $1$, base $[2,3]$ and height $\frac{1}{2}$, base $[3,4]$ and height $\frac{1}{3}$, and so on up to base $[n-1,n]$ and height $\frac{1}{n-1}$. Looking at these rectangles and the curve we see that
$$\int_1^n \frac{1}{x}\,dx\lt 1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}\lt 1+\int_1^{n} \frac{1}{x}\,dx.$$
We conclude that
$$\ln n \lt 1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots +\frac{1}{n}\lt 1+\ln n.$$
These inequalities are enough to prove the result.